# Different CSS files in Blazor Client-Side

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I have created an admin "area" in Blazor client-side that has it's own css file and should NOT have the default css file linked.

The VS project template links to the css in the head part of index.html.

How would I go about using different css files for different areas?
Right now I moved the css link to the different Layout files, but it just feels wrong.